# Does Allah know how we feel at any given time?

Tags: quran, allah

In the Qur'an it's described how Allah is closer to us than our jugular vein. Does that mean that Allah knows everything about us in a moment such as how we are feeling, our current condition, and all our subtle emotions about something?